# Writing a Junit test for a boolean method with no parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a class where I want to write a  junit test for.
This method has no parameters, can this method accordingly?

```
public class classTobeTested {

    @Self
    SlingHttpServletRequest request;

    static final String keyword = "hello";

    public boolean isActive() {
        boolean check;
        String pathChecker;
        pathChecker = (request.getRequestURL()).toString();
        check= pathChecker.contains(keyword);

        return check;

    }

}
```

This would be the testing class i had in mind

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class testclasstobetested {


    @Test
    public void TestclassTobeTested() throws Exception{
        classTobeTested  CTT = new classTobeTested();

        assertFalse(CTT.isActive("hello how are you"));
    }

}
```

I know my method does not take a parameter but has strings declared inside the method.
How can i use assertFalse correctly to test a non param method.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but you have have a look at the naming of you classes/methods. In general, class names should start with upper case, whereas method names should start with lower case. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/ for further reading.

Comment: agree, I changed the name of the classes for some privacy,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using annotations and Junit4 you can do it like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class testclasstobetested {

    @InjectMocks
    private classTobeTested CTT;

    @Mock
    private SlingHttpServletRequest request;

    @Test
    public void TestclassTobeTested() throws Exception{
        when(request.getRequestURL()).thenReturn(new StringBuffer("hello how are you"));

        assertFalse(CTT.isActive());
    }

}
```

Comment: i got this compilation failure  `no  suitable method found for thenReturn(java.lang.String)`

Comment: is it because `when((request.getRequestURL()).thenReturn` does not have .toString()?

Comment: It's because the method `request.getRequestURL()` returns a StringBuffer. I updated my answer, it should work now.

Comment: good catch, how long did it take you to get good at writing Junit test?

Comment: Some years ;) Please accept my answer if you are satisfied

Comment: did you delete the annotations line  `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Comment: Yes because if you use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` you don't need to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`, it's redundant.